# How to use smarty to translate a website?

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I want to use SMARTY to make a multi langage website.

I read this article: 
http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/creating_multilingual_website_smarty

However it does not work with smarty3 and I don't know exactly how these configs work: I am new to smarty.

ex: my website content is now

hello world, how are you

Can I use spaces in my variables so, I don't have to rewrite it all like:

{$hello_world_how_are_you}

but I would rather keep something like

**{hello world, how are you}** 
or

**/#hello world, how are you#/**

To avoid to rewrite slugs to each phrase I have to translate

Answer (score 0):

You can use array syntax

For example

```
{$lang['hello world, how are you']}
```

This have another advantage that you don't pollute your variable scope.